# How to rewrite this in terms of R.nthArg

Tags: ramda.js

I understand that `R.nthArg` returns a function which returns its nth argument. But I don't know how I can use it with my function below:

```
const REG = /^\s*$/;
const string = R.test(REG);
const result = (errorText) => (value) => string(value) ? errorText : null

result(translate(message));
```

### Sample usage

```js
const testString = R.test(/^\s*$/);

// const validator = (errorText) => (value) => 
//  testString(value) ? errorText : null;  

const validator = R.curry((errorText, value) =>      
  testString(value) ? errorText : null);  

const valid = validator('my Error');  

console.log('resultOne ' + valid('ololo')); 
console.log('resultTwo ' + valid(''));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you want to do with `nthArg`,  If the answer from OriDrori does not solve this for you, can you add some additional explanation?

Comment: Hello @ScottSauyet !
The first time I tried to do this task to use `R.curry`, as OriDrori suggested. But my mentor said that I can improve my solution with `R.nthArg`. The goal is to not show the arguments

Comment: What I was looking for is more about *what* you're trying to do.  It certainly looks as though you're dealing with a translation and potential error message.  We can easily dummy up a translation function -- I usually use `R.toUpper` for such tasks -- but we don't know where `errorText` or `message` comes from.  So my question is twofold: what exactly is the code supposed to accomplish, and what are some reasonable sample input values and their corresponding outputs?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Run this code, please in [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0) 

````const testString = R.test(/^\s*$/);

// const validator = (errorText) => (value) =>
//  testString(value) ? errorText : null;

const validator = R.curry((errorText, value) => 
    testString(value) ? errorText : null);

const valid = validator('my Error');

console.log('resultOne ' + valid('ololo'));
console.log('resultTwo ' + valid(' '));````

Comment: I added that to the question. But in the future you can always [edit] your own posts with the link between the question and the comments.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`nthArg`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#nthArg) was written in the early days of Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of Ramda and a core team member.)  It was a way to make point-free functions which were otherwise difficult to write that way.  There are a few other functions like this, such as [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge), but mostly the advice from the Ramda team now is to not make a fetish of point-free code.  It should only be used when it makes the code more readable.  `nthArg` and the rest rarely do so, and so should mostly be avoided.

However, if you're really interested, here's one point-free version of `validator` that has the same behavior as the snippet in the question:

```js
const testString = R.test(/^\s*$/);

const validator = R.curryN (2) (
  R.ifElse (
    R.pipe (R.nthArg (1), testString), 
    R.nthArg (0), 
    R.always (null)
  )
)

const valid = validator ('my Error');  

console.log('resultOne ' + valid('ololo')); 
console.log('resultTwo ' + valid(' '));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Clearly that's horrible.  The original version is much more readable:

```js
const validator = (errorText) => (value) => 
  testString(value) ? errorText : null;
```

and if you want Ramda-style currying, you can just use this one:

```js
const validator = R.curry((errorText, value) =>      
  testString(value) ? errorText : null);
```

So, while I know nothing about your mentor, I'm going to disagree with her or him about how to best structure this.  If this is only a learning exercise for point-free or for `nthArg` specifically, then this is fine.  Otherwise, I think the original vanilla version is quite a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for [R.curry](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry):

```
const string = R.test(REG);
const result = R.curry((errorText, value) => string(value) ? errorText : null)

result(translate(message));
```